# file exporting DRAFT notation

Tags: lyx, pdf, draft, export

I am exporting my lyx file to pdf by going to
File -> Export -> PDF (pdflaetx)

However, when I open my exported pdf file I get a notation at the top of some of the pages with the word DRAFT followed by the date the file was exported i.e. DRAFT: November 7, 2014

How can I remove this notation? (I use lyx 2.1)

Comment: Do you have any options set in Document > Settings > Custom ? Can you please post a minimal example? See http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: problem solved! a \lhead{\textit{DRAFT: \today}} command was in the preamble that I hadn't seen before

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error of the op not to comment a command that prints "Draft".

Comment: @Paul thanks for posting back the solution to your problem! That is much appreciated (many users just take off once they figure out the problem).